# C++ debugging doesn't start in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, cygwin, mingw

I am Windows 10 with Cygwin installed. I am able to run c++ code from vscode's terminal as follows:

[image]

However I am not able to configure the debug file in vscode.
When I try to add launch configuration, it gives me following options:

[image]

After selecting "gdb (Launch)". It created following launch configuration:

```
{
    "name": "(gdb) Launch",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
            "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
            "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
}
```

I have set `preLaunchTask` and `miDebuggerPath` myself. `preLaunchTask` looks like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Now, when I go to test.cpp tab and hit debug button, it first shows build task:

[image]

followed by debug status:

[image]

But the debugging / execution starts after this. It does not hit the breakpoint also, nor does it print the program output `Hello World 123`. Why is this so? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try restarting the system and while booting open the system debug panel to check all the functioning are fine.
send the screenshot for the above results, what you see there.

Thanks !

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, the error is very frustrating to me. Now, I am not able to even set it up on eclipse.